# Invalid Column Name SQL Server; even though the column is present

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba

I have a code of around 813 lines. The code is executed through excel macro automatically. There is an Error:

> Executing the query "  Select    A.LoanKey AS LoanKey,   MAX(B.LoanKey)..."
>   failed with the following error: "Invalid column name '**LoanProductKey**'.

This column is used in many places. 
eg:

```
SELECT A.*,B.*
from someDatabase.dbo.tableA A
JOIN someDatabase.dbo.tableB B ON A.LoanProductKey = B.LoanProductKey
```

I have checked and made sure that both tables have that column.

**Running the whole code manually doesn't throw any error.**

So I am not able to debug the code too.

Comment: Post the whole query that leads to error

Comment: Provide a part from real code where you're using `LoanProductKey`.

Comment: Could you check if the SQL uses a LoanProductKey somewhere without an alias for the table?  Because Sql server likes to know from which table you need it if it's available in more than 1 table you join.

Comment: Check if these objects are tables or if there are computed columns which are referencing this missing column.

Comment: @LukStorms No, all tables are given with alias name and while referencing the column name, alias is used.

Comment: Does the error say at which line the error is? Because then you could break down the problem by trying to select a few values from the column from that table alone, and see if that at least works.

Comment: @LukStorms no it doesn't provide any line numbers. Only error message: ERROR OCCURED !!!, In SQL Settings -> for SQL Seq No : 1 ERROR IS -> Executing the query "  Select    A.LoanKey AS LoanKey,   MAX(B.LoanKey)..." failed with the following error: "Invalid column name 'LoanProductKey'.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, everybody. The problem was with temp table. What happened was, first temp table was created with a single column from someTable. Later though the table was drop and re-created with LoanProductKey column, the query was referring to the first created table. so I changed the name of second temp table. There is no issue now.

Answer (score 0):

In excel write your code within the below function which removes the non-printing characters of your excel test.

```
= CLEAN (Write your queries here)
```

Comment: The excel picks up query from the particular code location provided.

Comment: can you provide your excel sheet